# Angular scopes and losing binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-resource

I haven't been able to find anywhere else that really helps me understand my Angular problem here but I suspect it has something to do with inheritance that I haven't completely grasped yet.

I'm doing an ng-repeat of a custom directive and seeing strange behavior when attempting to update the collection from a resource. Here is the plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QXAFvQix8oUiVMlMuEXw

To see what the issue is, click on the 'Finish Registration' button which retrieves the json from the resource and replaces the current collection.  What I expect is for the cards to be replaced by updated cards, but what is happening is that the first 2 cards seem to no longer be bound to the scope (or are somehow zombified) and 2 new cards are added. Each subsequent update updates the new cards as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into an issue with the isolated scope accidentally leaking into other directives defined on the same element.

However, this has been addressed and [fixed in Angular v1.2.4](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#isolate-scope-only-exposed-to-directives-with-property) in [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7).

Hence, this version (with only Angular updated) works: http://plnkr.co/edit/kufU5fI90j2lj2jdyLBx?p=preview

The way to write it such that it is AngularJS version agnostic is keeping the relationship between the scopes perfectly clear by nesting the directives:

```html
  <div ng-repeat="student in currentUser.studentCollection">
     <div student-card  
       student="student" 
       unit-schools="unitSchools"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Good to know the issue here and the workaround for now.